# How to use two different sort-keys to sort a list when the first sort-key is same

Tags: python, sorting, data-structures

In python, is this possible to use two different sort-keys to sort a list?
We have a list that contains three sub-lists as shown,

```
list = [ [1,2,3], [1,1,2],[13,3,4] ]
```

I want to utilize `heapq.nsmallest` to sort it, where the first element in each sub-list is the sort-key. If the first sub-list (e.g., `[1,2,3]`) and the second sub-list (e.g., `[1,1,2]`) have the same sort-key (e.g., `1`), I want to use the ***second element*** as a new sort-key.

Thus the expected output is:

```
orderedlist = [ [1,1,2],[1,2,3],[13,3,4] ]
```

Comment: wait, are you trying to sort the list? Will `heapq.nsmallest` be a situation where n == len(thelist)?

Comment: What's wrong with just using `sorted(list)`?

Comment: Just use `heapq.nsmallest` without the `key` argument. The sublists, `list`s themselves, define the comparison dunders: `__ge__`, `__lt__`, etc. and will result in your desired ordering by default.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `key` argument in `sorted`:

```
list1 = [ [1,2,3], [1,1,2],[13,3,4] ]

print(sorted(list1,key = lambda x: x[1]))
```

output:

```
[[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [13, 3, 4]]
```